# AssertionError when using variable instead of a literal

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Python.  I have a code like the following.  Why do I get an AssertionError, when I use `assert <some variable> in driver.page_source`?  Instead of the variable if I use a literal, such as a string, the test passes.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import sys
from instream import InStream
from outstream import OutStream
import stdio

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        s = 'Ireland'
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert s in driver.page_source

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I cannot replicate, add a full runnable example

Comment: Are you saying `assert "Ireland" in  driver.page_source` passes and `assert s in  driver.page_source` fails? Or `self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)` passes and `assert s in  driver.page_source` fails?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think that were just 2 different executions - one had the results loaded, one did not..the OP made a wrong conclusion. It is similar to how they say they saw UFOs :)

Comment: @alecxe,  lol,  well as long as nobody got probed ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *timing* problem (reproduced it as well). The assertion is made at the moment the search results are not loaded yet and, hence, `Ireland` is not yet there in the `page_source`. Add a wait via [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to make the test more reliable:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

s = 'Ireland'
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# wait for results to be visible
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-recent-events li")))

assert s in driver.page_source
```

Note that `.list-recent-events li` is a *CSS selector* that matches the first event in the resulting event list.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  That fixed it.